# orientjs: upsert edge in transaction

Tags: javascript, orientdb, orientjs

How can I upsert an edge in a transaction using orientjs? My current implementation upserts two vertices and **always** creates a new edge:

```
function add(db, from, edge, to, cb) {
  cb = cb || function() {};
  log(
    '[' + from.clazz + ']' + JSON.stringify(from.attributes) + ' ' +
    '-[' + edge.clazz + ']' + JSON.stringify(edge.attributes) + '> ' +
    '[' + to.clazz + ']' + JSON.stringify(to.attributes)
  );
  db.let('source', function(s) {
      s.update(from.clazz)
        .set(from.attributes)
        .upsert()
        .where(from.attributes)
        .return('after @this');
    })
    .let('destination', function(d) {
      d.update(to.clazz)
        .set(to.attributes)
        .upsert()
        .where(to.attributes)
        .return('after @this');
    })
    .let('edge', function(e) {
      e.create('EDGE', edge.clazz)
        .from('$source')
        .to('$destination')
        .set(edge.attributes);
    })
    .commit()
    .return('$edge')
    .all()
    .then(cb);
}
```

Comment: Which version are you using? Starting from 2.2 you can use `UPDATE EDGE`  See: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Update-Edge.html

Comment: orientdb is on 2.1.19, orientjs on 2.2.1. I might be able to upgrade both. But in the doc I can not see an `UPSERT` for `UPDATE EDGE`. Will an `UPDATE EDGE` automatically upsert the edge?

Comment: You're right, there isn't upsert for update edge. If your edge already exists, you can use update.

Answer (score 0):

I've not found any upsert method for an edge in OrientJS, but you can prevent creation of edges `twice` between the same source and destination. You need to just

- Create a `UNIQUE index` while creating an edge migration.

Here is the migration code for creating an edge with a unique index :

```
exports.up = (db) => {
  return db.class.create('HasApplied', 'E')
    .then((hasApplied) => {
      return hasApplied.property.create(
        [{
          name: 'out',
          type: 'link',
          linkedClass: 'Consultant',
          mandatory: true
        }, {
          name: 'in',
          type: 'link',
          linkedClass: 'Job',
          mandatory: true
        }, {
          name: 'technicalQuestions',
          type: 'embedded'
        }, {
          name: 'technicalAnswers',
          type: 'embedded'
        }, {
          name: 'behavioralQuestions',
          type: 'embedded'
        }, {
          name: 'behavioralAnswers',
          type: 'embedded'
        }, {
          name: 'artifacts',
          type: 'embeddedset'
        }, {
          name: 'comments',
          type: 'string',
        }, {
          name: 'createdAt',
          type: 'datetime'
        }, {
          name: 'updatedAt',
          type: 'datetime'
        }]
      );
    })
    .then(() => db.query('CREATE INDEX HasApplied.out_in ON HasApplied (out, in) UNIQUE'));
};
```

Then when your code trying to run transaction containing let block :

```
.let('edge', function(e) {
      e.create('EDGE', edge.HasApplied)
        .from('$source')
        .to('$destination')
        .set(edge.attributes);
    })
```

will throw `db level error` if found already exist edge between the same **$source** and **$destination** .

I hope this will definitely help you :)

Comment: and so how do you then use `upsert` for the edge in there?